# element.className has no effect on html

Tags: javascript

Im tryng to dynamcally add a className nothing happens and i get no errors

```
function    update(element,content,klass)   {   

    var p   =   element.firstChild  ||  document.createElement("p");    
    p.textContent   =   content;    

    if(klass)   {
    p.className = klass;
    console.log(p.className);
    }
    element.appendChild(p);
}
```

This is where i call the update func

```
function check(answer,index){
    if(answer === quiz.questions[index].answer){
        update($feedback,"Correct!","right");
        score++;
    }
    else{
        update($feedback,"Wrong!","wrong");
    }

}
```

the console.log className output is correct..."wrong" and "right", not sure why i dont get the class added to my paragraphs

Comment: because `p.setAtrribute  =("class" , klass);` is wrong in mutliple ways.... Look at the documentation for setAttribute. ANd after you do that, search for a better way to add a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `setAttribute` method instead of invoking it, though setting the property is nicer.

```
p.className = klass;
```

---

Also, if the `.firstChild` is a text node (which may just be whitespace), that class addition will have no effect. Instead, use `.firstElementChild`.

```
var p = element.firstElementChild || document.createElement("p");
```

---

Also, you should be aware that if there was indeed a `.firstElementChild`, then passing it to `.appendChild` will *relocate* it to the position of the *last* child. If you don't want that, then you should only do the appending if there was no element.

```
function update(element,content,klass) {   
    var p = element.firstElementChild || element.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));    
    p.textContent = content;    

    if(klass) {
        p.className = klass;
    }
}
```

Comment: ye firstElementChild did it! ty

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the setAttribute (Also misspelled in your code) function like this:

```
p.setAttribute("class", klass);
```